# How to upgrade a Rails 3.0 app to Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a Rails 3.0 app (technically 3.0.7) which I would like to upgrade to Rails 3.1 to make use of the new asset pipeline and other fancy new features. What is the best approach to doing this? Should I use the `rails new` generator, then copy everything from my old app over to the new one? What about version control? I already have my old app using Git.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just upgraded one of my apps from 3.0.9 to 3.1.0, here's my approach, your mileage might vary:

Edit Gemfile, change Rails gem version

```
gem 'rails', '3.1.0'
```

Also adds new gems introduced in 3.1.0

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

run `bundle update rails`

Then run `rake rails:update` and resolve conflicts.

Move your css/javascript/images etc to `app/assets` folder, make sure there's an `application.js` and an `application.css` file (you might want to take a look at those two from newly created 3.1.0 projects)

Include css/javascript links in your layout file like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to update RVM to the latest version: `rvm get latest` or by running the install script again if RVM is too old, then update RubyGems: `gem update --system`, then update bundler: `gem install bundler`

Comment: I had some conflicts when I ran `bundle update rails` so I had to run `bundle update` instead

Comment: As far as the assets directory, I just created a dummy 3.1 app and copied the assets directory structure over to my old app

Comment: Also note that references to images (in stylesheets for example) will no longer be `/images/photo.jpg` it will be `/assets/photo.jpg` (no reference to an images directory). That one got me for a bit.

Comment: If you are "picking frameworks", eg, if you have replaced "require 'rails/all'" in application.rb with a list of the frameworks you need, you must add "require 'sprockets/railtie'"

Answer (score 1):

Get familiar with rails 3.1, here are the resources:
http://jasonrudolph.com/blog/2011/06/06/helpful-resources-for-upgrading-to-rails-3-1/

The most important thing are your current test, make sure you have a good test coverage of your 3.0 app before you start.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new branch in your Git repo.

Take a look at the **[Rails 3.1 Example Apps](http://railsapps.github.com/)** if you are using Devise, RSpec or Cucumber because they will give you a good working reference implementation. If not, just use `rails new` to create a simple Rails 3.1 app.

Then use a file compare tool (such as FileMerge or Changes on Mac OS X) to identify where the Rails 3.1 code differs from your 3.0 app.

Answer (score 0):

I have just done this today with an app from 3.0.9
Take a look at this blog, its pretty simple.

http://davidjrice.co.uk/2011/05/25/how-to-upgrade-a-rails-application-to-version-3-1-0.html

Its just a matter of changing gem file, a few config variables,moving a few assets and creating some css and js manifest files, shouldn't take more than an hour.

Answer (score 0):

copy this gems to your gem file replacing the old once 
    gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

```
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

All you have to do is run `rake rails:update`

you can also run `rake -T` to see some cool rake task that you would need